Bootstrap form not showing validation when used browser saved data
In the below code the bootstrap validation which is the green tick does not show when the data saved in the browser, but it works fine when the data is entered manually.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags and Bootstrap CSS -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    /* Optional: Adjust form width on larger screens */
    .registration-form {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    /* Remove autofill background color in Chrome */
    input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px white inset !important; /* Changes background to white */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000 !important; /* Ensures text remains black */
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="registration-form">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title text-center mb-4">Register</h3>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <!-- First Name and Last Name -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" placeholder="First Name" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter your first name (letters only).
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" pattern="^[A-Za-z]+$" placeholder="Last Name" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter your last name (letters only).
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Email -->
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="emailAddress" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a valid email address.
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Password -->
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" minlength="6" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a password with at least 6 characters.
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Confirm Password -->
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" minlength="6" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Passwords do not match.
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Terms and Conditions -->
          <div class="form-check mb-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="form-check-input" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="terms">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              You must agree to the terms and conditions.
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Submit Button -->
          <div class="d-grid">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap JS and custom validation script -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
(() => {
  'use strict';

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

  // Trigger validation for autofilled fields on page load
  const triggerAutofillValidation = () => {
    const autofillFields = document.querySelectorAll('input:-webkit-autofill');

    // Dispatch an input event for each autofilled field to trigger validation
    autofillFields.forEach(field => {
      field.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
    });
  };

  // On window load, trigger autofill validation
  window.addEventListener('load', triggerAutofillValidation);

  // Loop over each form and prevent submission if invalid
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    // Password and Confirm Password fields
    const password = form.querySelector('#password');
    const confirmPassword = form.querySelector('#confirmPassword');

    // Event listener to validate password match
    confirmPassword.addEventListener('input', function () {
      if (confirmPassword.value !== password.value) {
        confirmPassword.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
      } else {
        confirmPassword.setCustomValidity('');
      }
    });

    // Form submission event
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      // Check for validity
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }

      // Add Bootstrap validation classes
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);

  });
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>  

See below images for reference:
When data entered manually
When using browser saved data
I also want to get the tick when the browser saved data is also used. So, how can I do so?

As per my search the issue is that the user agent stylesheet sets the background-image to none !important, making them non-overridable which means our background image won’t show when users select saved data. According to the MDN documentation, we can’t easily change this. You can check out: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill
